# How to add an external dependency into a Swift project using Bazel (without using Cocoapod)

Tags: ios, xcode, bazel, tensorflow-lite

The dependency I'm trying to integrate is TensorFlowLite:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/swift

I'm already using Carthage and SwiftPackageManager to manage dependencies of an Xcode project.
Since TensorFlowLite supports Bazel, I tried to download, build, and link the dependency using the Bazel configuration.

I downloaded the Bazel iOS demo app from here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/tutorial

And followed the instruction in this page:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/ios-app.html

When I try to build the demo iOS app using the following command:

```
bazel build //ios-app
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: /Users/nebil/Downloads/examples-master/tutorial/ios-app/BUILD:15:14: 
no such package '@TensorFlowLite//tensorflow/lite/experimental/swift': BUILD file not found in directory 'tensorflow/lite/experimental/swift' of external repository @TensorFlowLite. 
Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '//ios-app:TensorFlowLite'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//ios-app:ios-app' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
```

In the main WORKSPACE file I added the following dependency:

```
git_repository(
    name = "TensorFlowLite",
    remote = "https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow",
    tag = "v2.2.0",
)
```

And the BUILD file of the ios_app package:

```
load("@build_bazel_rules_apple//apple:ios.bzl", "ios_application")
load("@build_bazel_rules_swift//swift:swift.bzl", "swift_library")

swift_library(
  name = 'TensorFlowLite',
  deps = [
      "@TensorFlowLite//tensorflow/lite/experimental/swift:TensorFlowLite",
  ],
)

ios_application(
    name = "ios-app",
    bundle_id = "Google.UrlGet",
    families = [
        "iphone",
        "ipad",
    ],
    infoplists = [":UrlGet/UrlGet-Info.plist"],
    launch_storyboard = "UrlGet/UrlGetViewController.xib",
    minimum_os_version = "8.0",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [:TensorFlowLite"],
)
```

I'm using the same project structure of the same project and simply added a new dependency to the main app.

The build is failing because the BUILD file is missing from the third party code, but this is not true:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/swift/BUILD.apple

I'm not an expert with Bazel but I don't see why this shouldn't be possibile. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Thank you